# PHP Cron Job--> Compare date in MySQL with Current Date plus 7 days and send email not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Why do I receive the email today(11-11-2017) from the following **CRON JOB** which says Compare date in MySQL with Current Date plus 7 days and send email even though none of the records from my MySql table are not matching the specified SELECT * FROM rule below ?

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'stdeja_genek', 'haslo', 'stdeja_genek');


    $tbl_2 = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM 
    klienci WHERE date(Data) BETWEEN CURTIME() AND 
    DATE_ADD(CURTIME(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);");

        if($tbl_2->num_rows == 2) {

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
    foreach($tbl_2 as $email => $details) {        
        $fullname = $details['Klient'] . ' ' . $details['Data'];
            $mail->addAddress('piterdeja@gmail.com');
            $mail->setFrom('system_przypomnien_hosting@powiadomienia.pl');
            $mail->Subject = "Hosting - system przypomnień";
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = "W dniu {$details['Data']} kończy się hosting klientowi {$details['Klient']} na KWOTĘ {$details['Cena']}, hosting to {$details['Hosting']}";

                        if ($mail->send())
                echo "Formularz został wysłany. Postaramy się odpowiedzieć jak najszybciej.";
            else
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

    }

        }


    ?>
```

This is my table records from MySql:

```
ID  | Client  |    Data    | Hosting   | Price |
    |         |            |           |       |
    |         | 2017-11-14 | Heineken  | 500   |
    |         | 2017-11-12 | Hestia    | 200   |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
    |         | 0000-00-00 |           |       |
```

It should only select day being the result of --> right now + 7 days, but somehow I receive email today 11-11-2017

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 'WHERE' in your query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between